# Bootstrap 3.3.5. collapsed menu won't expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I literally spent hours looking for a solution here and elsewhere but whatever helps others, it does not seem to help me. So I want the bootstrap 3.3.5 menu for mobile screens to collapse and expand on click. Is there a problem with my code?

```
<!--navbar starts here-->    
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="callapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="Me navbar-brand">
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
      </div><!--end Me-->
    </div><!--end navbar-header-->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--end nav-->
  </div><!--end nav container-->
</div> <!--end navbar-->
```

I load jquery and bootstrap like this end the end of the body:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My code says Bootstrap 3.3.6, which I tried as well but without success. Same issue with 3.3.5

Comment: `callapse` should be `collapse` in your `data-toggle`. I feel bad pointing this out as you've spent hours on this :c once you change that it seems to [work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/bvpon0c4/)

Comment: @George I never feel bad when pointing out a typo. On the contrary. Especially when it's a hair-pulling one for the person seeking it.

Comment: Thx a lot, sometimes you are blind for your own typos!!
I appreciate you empathy, @George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change data-toggle="callapse" into data-toggle="collapse"
It will work fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!--navbar starts here-->    
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="Me navbar-brand">
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
      </div><!--end Me-->
    </div><!--end navbar-header-->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--end nav-->
  </div><!--end nav container-->
</div> <!--end navbar-->
```

Comment: Thats it!! omg, I spent 4 hours modifying, checking ^^^^

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code lacks the CSS files and you had a typo on the data-toggle of the button.

I updated the JS file of JQuery to the last v1.12

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!--navbar starts here-->    
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="Me navbar-brand">
          <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a>
      </div><!--end Me-->
    </div><!--end navbar-header-->
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="index.html">Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#faq">FAQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--end nav-->
  </div><!--end nav container-->
</div> <!--end navbar-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: CSS files were there, just not in this part I c/p-ed. It was the typo...